# Custom JS variable for GTM

Tags: javascript, variables, google-tag-manager

[image: This i need to return for product page]

[image: And this i have to return for listing pages, trough loop]

```
    function() {
  var prodRate=document.querySelector('div.summary.entry-summary > div.woocommerce-product-rating > p').innerText.replace('Product Rate:','');
  var rating = document.querySelectorAll('.star-rating');
  var starRating =[];
  for(i=0;i<rating.length;i++){
  starRating.push(rating[i].innerText)};
  
  var averageRating = starRating || prodRate;  

 return averageRating;
}
```

I have to return one of the values that is displayed as product rating. On listing page this rating is displayed as "aria-label", and on product page as the value of p. How can i set a one single variable, that returns the needed value of product rating.
I am traying above mentioned function, but it doesn't work properly.
Thank you a lot and sorry for such newbie question.

Comment: This code couldn't return undefined in either way: `starRating` is an array and `prodRate` is a string. So clarify your question with details and more data to reproduce the issue. It would be extremely helpful if you would give a piece of HTML, show invocation of the function and the place where the wrong result occurs.

Comment: @PaulRumkin thank you for your feedback. I've added screens from my site and more details. hope it is clearer now )

Comment: @PaulRumkin this code can return undefined, because GTM returns undefined when the function throws an error (e.g. when you run this on page load before the DOM element the function tries to access actually exist).

Comment: @EikePierstorff  I meant this exact function couldn't return undefined, it can throw instead. And it seems like it is what is going on here. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Olga there is an error in the CSS selector `div.woocommerce-product-rating > p` there is one more element between woocommerce-product-rating div and p element. It's not clear if the whole selector is invalid, or this part only, screenshots don't contain other DOM-tree parts. So I'd suggest you to test selectors manually in console. Probably `.woocommerce-product-rating p` would be enough. But anyway make sure your selectors work properly.